# How to make an horizontal scrollbar responsively fit to the div width?

Tags: html, css, scroll, responsive-design, scrollbar

I have an horizontal scrollbar `class="filter_list"` into a wrapper div `class="wrapper"`. I want this scrollbar to be always 100% of the wrapper div and I want this wrapper div to be responsive.

It's working fine if I only have one item in my filter list but as soon as I put more than the wrapper width size, it's not responsive anymore.

Here are some pictures to illustrate the problem :

Responsive and working fine :

[OK](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/NNLDr5838lOr6ykTD5o8_6R2rhKUb5-tzCBuusIZMEPfeqfcAxTDYNAD4DFEiBHqBTdtTGe5fw3WL7tZJzjwp72SUPkDEDYRSMkjwzmKlsfhvz43PAKqxejE2mqXjVEj2xLebxKS=w200)

The scrollbar is blocking the width of the wrapper that doesn't shrink to fit the dimension of the window (we can see that the picture of the girl is no longer it's 100% square size):

[NOT OK](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/7daP4bKohEJzG7gCxjFxS-UL5VCHFP0R0ziVE4ECknsHW7cpx3HqHEec-qacW7umAxh7IlRJ4T_asHX9CNRd5fO7e6iZfzrJvq2VFsz8fEq9qj9eoMt4ZJ_6AEwbjMdFl3LC0x4x=w200)

Here is the code :

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.magic_wand {
  margin: 15px 0px 20px;
  max-width: 50px;
}

.ico_magic_wand {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.picture_preview {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  height: 100px;
}

.picture_preview img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.filter_list {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
}

.filter:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.filter {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="magic_wand">
      <img src="img/ico/magic_wand.png" class="ico_magic_wand">
    </div>
    <div class="picture_preview">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1527514086375-0a7bae9089be">
    </div>

    <div class="filter_list">
      <div class="filter">

      </div>
      <div class="filter">

      </div>
      <div class="filter">

      </div>
      <div class="filter">

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

I would like to understand why the `div class="filter_list"` width won't shrink with it's parent div while reducing the width of the window and how to fix the problem, thanks a lot !

Comment: Do u want the blue box adjused by window width? always in 4 column?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.. I can't understand your question.. it may ur expectation,, else explain it clearly..

**css**

```
.filter {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150px;
    width: 21.3%;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.filter:nth-child(4n+4) {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Please remove ur css code and add this codes.. I think display:flex; is the issue for ur code..

```
body {
  margin:0px;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.magic_wand {
  margin: 15px auto 20px;
  max-width: 50px;
}
.picture_preview {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  height: 100px;
}
.picture_preview img {
  height: 100%;
}
.filter_list {
  width: auto;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
}
.filter:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
.filter {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: I mean it fixes the problem of responsiveness but I still don't understand why my code doesn't work.

Comment: And your solution also has another problem : the square ratio of the `.filter` is not kept while shrinking

Comment: Probably ur code not working .. because the width u added in px.. so its stranged.. finally, do u want same width and height with bottom scroll? Is this correct?

Comment: yeah that's the idea !

Comment: I was searching about conserving the square ratio to use your solution

Comment: yeah ! I just changed this : ```  .wrapper {
    max-width: 800px;
}
  .picture_preview {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
  .picture_preview img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}``` thanks

Comment: You just have to changed your code a little :) thanks for the help